# CoreData memory management

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks

I come from .NET world so memory management wasn't something I've given that much though in the past. So, this is the situation I'm in.. I have a method that searches DB and returns some data back to view controller:

```
- (NSArray *)getSomeData
{
    NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    //search DB
    [myArray addObject:@"Here I'm adding some objects"];
    return myArray;
}
```

and in my view controller i have a global variable NSArray *myGlobalData to witch I add my DB data:

```
myGlobalData = [DataManager getSomeData];
```

And when I run my application with allocations or leaks there's a memory leak. How can I avoid this? I tried with autorelease but it didn't help. What's standard way of dealing with return of init/allocated objects?

Comment: Don't call the method `get` anything;  just call it `someData`.  `get` has a very specific and special meaning.

Comment: I use "fetch" and "save" in my data layer naming conventions.. I asume that you're referring to getters and setters, but I just wanna clear things up because I'm new to ObjC and wanna learn as much as possible :) and I think this is a good advice in general!

Comment: That is fine;  `get` means that the method will be returning something by-reference, which is quite uncommon in Cocoa APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need....

```
 return [myArray autorelease];
```

But make sure you retain the array where you are using it....

Comment: so I return it with autorelease, and then retain it with self.myGlobalData.. And then release myGlobalData on unload or dealloc or whatever.. 

tnx.. I'll try that right away